# How to disable modal button if displayed cart item is empty?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im still learning PHP and Javascript. I display my cart item using modal but I don't have any idea how to disable the modal button if the displayed cart item is empty.

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="cartmodal" tabindex="-1" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Lihat Bahan Arkib</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-secondary" id="cart_table" style="width: 100%;">
                    <thead class="">
                        <tr class="">
                            <th>No.Rujukan & No.Penerimaan</th>
                            <th>Tajuk</th>
                            <th>Tindakan</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id='cartBody'>      
                        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
                            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $v){ ?>
                            <tr id="view-cart">
                            <td><?php echo $v['id_arkib'] ?> </td>
                            <td><?php echo $v['tajuk']?> </td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-danger mdi mdi-delete deleteitem" required>Padam</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php }
                        }?>         
                    </tbody>
                </table>              
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-mohon-cart" name="mohonbtn" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>pusat_sumber/penyelidik/permohonan_penyelidik.php">Mohon</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript:

```
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" disabled={cart.length > 0 ? false : true}>
```